Error when trying to use two different databases in the same function python
Im trying to merge two querys in a function, these querys are from two different databases. when i run them separatedely, they work fine. But when i try calling both in the same function, the second query (no matter the order, always the second to be executed) returns 'TABLE OR VIEW DOES NOT EXIST'. The querys are:
def execute_query1():
    pool_AVECOM = get_pool(IP_AVECOM, PORT_AVECOM, SERVICENAME_AVECOM, USERNAME_AVECOM, PW_AVECOM)
    conn1 = pool_AVECOM.acquire()
    cursor = conn1.cursor()
    query = """
    SELECT
        TEC.COD_RESPONSAVEL COD_TECNICO,
        TEC.NOM_RESPONSAVEL NOME_TECNICO,
        GRA.COD_CRIADOR_PROPRIETARIO COD_CRIADOR,
        GRA.NOM_GRANJA NOME_GRANJA,
        REPLACE(TRANSLATE(GRA.CGC_CPF_CRIADOR , '. - /' , ' '), ' ','') CGC_CPF_CRIADOR,
        LOT.NRO_LOTE LOTE,
        (CASE WHEN LOT.DAT_INICIAL_ALOJAMENTO > SYSDATE
            THEN NULL
            ELSE LOT.DAT_INICIAL_ALOJAMENTO
            END ) DAT_INICIAL_ALOJAMENTO,
        DECODE(F.TIPMOV,NULL,'ABERTO','FECHADO') STATUS,
        LOT.QTD_AVES_ALOJADAS,
        NVL(RPI.QTD_AVES_MORTAS, 0) MORTALIDADE,
        LOT.DAT_FECHAMENTO,
        LOT.COD_SEXO SEXO
    FROM AVECOM.FCFSLOT0 LOT
    JOIN AVECOM.FCFSGRA0 GRA ON GRA.COD_GRANJA = LOT.COD_GRANJA AND GRA.COD_CRIADOR_PROPRIETARIO = LOT.COD_CRIADOR AND LOT.COD_LOCAL = GRA.COD_LOCAL
    JOIN AVECOM.FCFSRES0 TEC ON TEC.COD_RESPONSAVEL = GRA.COD_RESPONSAVEL
    LEFT JOIN AVECOM.FCFSRPI0 RPI ON LOT.NRO_LOTE = RPI.NRO_LOTE
    LEFT JOIN AVECOM.FCFSPAV0 P ON LOT.NRO_LOTE = P.NRO_LOTE
    LEFT JOIN AVECOM.AVECOM_MIT F ON LOT.NRO_LOTE = F.CLOTE AND F.TIPMOV = 'P01016'
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND LOT.DAT_INICIAL_ALOJAMENTO >= ( SYSDATE - 130 )
    AND GRA.FLG_ATIVA = 1
    GROUP BY
    TEC.COD_RESPONSAVEL,
    TEC.NOM_RESPONSAVEL,
    GRA.COD_CRIADOR_PROPRIETARIO,
    GRA.NOM_GRANJA,
    REPLACE(TRANSLATE(GRA.CGC_CPF_CRIADOR , '. - /' , ' '), ' ',''),
    LOT.NRO_LOTE,
    (CASE WHEN LOT.DAT_INICIAL_ALOJAMENTO > SYSDATE
            THEN NULL
            ELSE LOT.DAT_INICIAL_ALOJAMENTO
            END ),
    DECODE(F.TIPMOV,NULL,'ABERTO','FECHADO'),
    LOT.QTD_AVES_ALOJADAS,
    NVL(RPI.QTD_AVES_MORTAS, 0),
    LOT.DAT_FECHAMENTO,   
    LOT.COD_SEXO
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    cursor.close()
    conn1.close()
    return result

# Função para executar a segunda query e retornar o resultado como um dicionário
def execute_query2():
    pool_TOTVS = get_pool(IP_TOTVS, PORT_TOTVS, SERVICENAME_TOTVS, USERNAME_TOTVS, PW_TOTVS)
    conn2 = pool_TOTVS.acquire()
    cursor = conn2.cursor()
    query = """
    SELECT
        A2_COD,
        A2_CGC,
        A2_NOME
    FROM
        U_C0OLTW_PR.SA2010
    WHERE D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = {row[1]: (row[0], row[2]) for row in cursor.fetchall()}
    print(result)
    cursor.close()
    conn2.close()
    return result

If i run them separatedely, they work, but when i call them like this:
def mainTEST():
    # Conectar ao primeiro banco de dados (substitua os detalhes da conexão conforme necessário)

    # Conectar ao segundo banco de dados (substitua os detalhes da conexão conforme necessário)

    # Executar a primeira consulta
    result1 = execute_query1()
    print(result1)
    teste.sleep(10)

    # Executar a segunda consulta
    result2 = execute_query2()
    print(result2)

    # Realizar a junção dos resultados
    # merged_result = merge_results(result1, result2)

    # Fechar as conexões
    # conn1.close()
    # conn2.close()
    # for row in merged_result:
    #     print(row)
    # Retornar o resultado
    # return merged_result

The second one return 'TABLE OR VIEW DOES NOT EXIST'
Can anybody help please?

Try returning both the results after exec  Both the queries, I think it's the return statements that is causing this behaviour
def execute_query1():
    ...
    cursor.execute(query)
    result1 = cursor.fetchall()
    ...
    cursor.close()
    conn1.close()

# Função para executar a segunda query e retornar o resultado como um dicionário
def execute_query2():
    ...
    cursor.execute(query)
    result2 = {row[1]: (row[0], row[2]) for row in cursor.fetchall()}
    cursor.close()
    conn2.close()
    return result1 result2 ```
   Something like this.

@JohnGordon, I am not familiar with oracle's python tools, but why would you not be able to connect, disconnect, and connect to another database?

Have you tried releasing the connection and closing the pool at the end of the function? The docs say you shouldn't have to do that, but it's worth a try.

@JohnGordon What do you mean? There are two different cursors, not one cursor for both databases.

@NishantSVispute How is that different from what they're doing? Each function executes one query, closes that connection, and returns that result.

@Barmar he says "I am trying to merge two queries in a function ...." so when a function encounters a return statement for the first query and since the 2 queries connect to 2 different DB the first query never really releases the connection and throws the error Table not found, this might be the root cause for this behaviour. Also, It is my assumption.

I thought mainTest() was the function that merges them, by calling the two execute_queryX() functions. But maybe I'm misunderstanding.

@Barmar Oh, I see.  I misinterpreted what they meant by "when i try calling both in the same function".

If you have a recent version of python-oracledb (the successor to cx_Oracle), then check print(conn1) and print(conn2) to check you are connected to the user you are supposed to be connected as.  If you have an older version, then execute SELECT USER FROM DUAL.  (At an architectural level, can you do the merge in SQL using a DBLINK from one DB to the other?  This could be significantly faster than fetching both sets of data into Python)
